# Vue project and googleapis - will not build - child_process errors

Tags: node.js, google-api, vue.js, npm-install, vue-cli

### Goal

Install and build the googleapis package within a vue-cli project.

### Example

https://github.com/ChaddPortwine/test-googleapis

To create this example I simply:

1. `vue init webpack test-googleapis`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install googleapis --save`, `npm install google-auth-library --save`
4. `npm run dev` (so far, okay, app builds and runs)
5. Add line, `import googleapis from 'googleapis'` to `main.js`
6. `npm run dev` (ERR **Child_Process**)

### Errors

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 13 errors                                                      11:16:12 AM

These dependencies were not found:

* child_process in ./node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js
* fs in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/index.js, ./node_modules/googleapis/lib/googleapis.js and 5 others
* net in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js and 1 other
* tls in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs net tls
```

### Question

How do I get the app to build with `googleapis`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting these errors because the googleapis library is a Node library, as in, it does not work on the client side (browser), so Webpack can't handle it properly.

You can use it in Node based back-ends such as Express, but not in a client side Vue app - it might work with a server-side rendered Vue app via Nuxt, not sure though, haven't tried.

Comment: 8bit, do you know if [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) could be used as the Node back-end for the googleapis package? There are [examples of 3rd party APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#integrate_with_third-party_services_and_apis) working with Cloud Functions, included a few Google Services.

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but by the looks if it, it seems you can, as it runs on node. The docs seem pretty detailed, so just go and try it out.

Comment: Yep, Cloud Functions let you use node.js Google API packages.

This [excellent playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) by Jen Person was the perfect companion to the [Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

Comment: Any guidance on how you might be able to do it with Nuxt?  I've been searching for a solution but can't seem to figure it out.